Not able to change the color of status bar in android studio latest
I am trying to change the color of status bar. I have tried using the android:statusBarColor tag in themes.xml file but nothing is happening.
I have tried the android:statusBarColor tag in themes.xml file but it does not work.
The android studio version is jellyfish. But when i tried in older android studio version, it worked perfectly. Please help me out!!
The theme file->
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/teal</item>


    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Base.Theme.MyApplication" />

</resources>


In the title of your question you ask how to change the color of the status bar of Android Studio, the content of the question seems to be more about the app that you develop using Android Studio. Which one is it? The solution to the latter would have nothing to do with Android Studio, though.
